# Regex issue in python

Tags: python, regex

I have a regex "**`value=4020a345-f646-4984-a848-3f7f5cb51f21`**"

```
if re.search(      "value=\w*|\d*\-\w*|\d*\-\w*|\d*\-\w*|\d*\-\w*|\d*", x ):
    x = re.search( "value=\w*|\d*\-\w*|\d*\-\w*|\d*\-\w*|\d*\-\w*|\d*", x )
    m = x.group(1)
```

**`m`** only gives me `4020a345`, not sure why it does not give me the entire `"4020a345-f646-4984-a848-3f7f5cb51f21"`

Can anyone tell me what i am doing wrong?

Comment: `"value=4020a345-f646-4984-a848-3f7f5cb51f21".split('=')`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should match what you want, if all the strings are of the form you've shown:

```
value=((\w*\d*\-?)*)
```

You can also use this website to validate your regular expressions:
http://regex101.com/

Comment: @user2921139 this will also match value=4020a345-.is dis expected?

Answer (score 3):

try out this regex, looks like you are trying to match a GUID

```
value=[0-9a-f]{8}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{12}
```

Answer (score 1):

The below regex works as you expect.

```
value=([\w*|\d*\-\w*|\d*\-\w*|\d*\-\w*|\d*\-\w*|\d*]+)
```

Comment: No it does not.. he is trying to match hex.. the one above matches alot more than hex..

Comment: He/she doesn't require Hex in the original post. If it is a condition, how about this: value=((?:[a-fA-F0-9]+-?)+)

Answer (score 0):

You can get the subparts of the value as a list

```
txt = "value=4020a345-f646-4984-a848-3f7f5cb51f21"
parts = re.findall('\w+', txt)[1:]
```

parts is `['4020a345', 'f646', '4984', 'a848', '3f7f5cb51f21']`

if you really want the entire string

```
full = "-".join(parts)
```

**A simple way**

```
full = re.findall("[\w-]+", txt)[-1]
```

full is `4020a345-f646-4984-a848-3f7f5cb51f21`

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to match on some hex numbers, that is why this regex is more correct than using `[\w\d]`

```
pattern = "value=([0-9a-fA-F]{8}-([0-9a-fA-F]{4}-){3}[0-9a-fA-F]{12})"
data = "value=4020a345-f646-4984-a848-3f7f5cb51f21"
res = re.search(pattern, data)
print(res.group(1))
```

If you dont care about the regex safety, aka checking that it is correct hex, there is no reason not to use simple string manipulation like shown below.

```
>>> data = "value=4020a345-f646-4984-a848-3f7f5cb51f21"
>>> print(data[7:])
020a345-f646-4984-a848-3f7f5cb51f21
>>> # or maybe
...
>>> print(data[7:].replace('-',''))
020a345f6464984a8483f7f5cb51f21
```

Answer (score 0):

```
value=([\w\d]*\-[\w\d]*\-[\w\d]*\-[\w\d]*\-[\w\d]*)
```

Try this.Grab the capture.Your regex was not giving the whole as you had used `|` operator.So if regex on left side of `|` get satisfied it will not try the latter part.

See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/hQ1rP0/45